# Transitioning hover off svg paths

Tags: css, svg

Just wondering how to make a svg path transition ease back to its default position on hover off.

```
<svg>
 <path></path>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
svg path{ transition: transform 0.5s ease; transform: none}
svg:hover path{ transition: transform 0.5s ease; transform: translateY(10px)}
```

This only works for the hover however, not for the hover off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me, of course your hover off is applied to the whole svg in your question. Don't you just want to apply it to the path?

```css
svg path{ transition: transform 0.5s ease; transform: none}
svg path:hover{ transition: transform 0.5s ease; transform: translateY(10px)}
```

```html
<svg>
 <path stroke="black" stroke-width="15" pointer-events="all" d="M20 20l50 0"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: I actually wanted the hover to act on the svg and the transition on the path, so my code was right all along. The problem was a typo... Thx anyways!